# Structure to avoid too many files in a single folder (ex: ab/cd/abcdef): Name of this technique?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, technical, computing

When you have thousands or millions of files in a single directory, there can be drawbacks.

A strategy is to avoid that situation is to distribute the files into sub-folders whose name is for instance the first few letters of the filename, or the first few letters of the filename's hash. That allows the file to be easily findable, while having no more than *n* files per folder. Example:

Before:

```
/abcdef
/fewrof
/abcdea
...
```

After:

```
/ab/cd/abcdef
/fe/wr/fewrof
/ab/cd/abcdea
...
```

This is a very frequently used technique. Is there an English name for it? If not, what is the nearest word or expression that encompasses it?

Comment: What is the name in your language? Sometimes a translation works (sometimes not).

Comment: @Mitch: In this field my language is English, so I don't have a name for that, sorry.

Comment: Engineering note: This idea may backfire; you might actually want `/ab/cd/ef` instead. The goal is to have name diversity in each directory.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is simply called a *hashed directory structure* (or *hashed folder structure* if you're talking Microsoft). Even your example is still using a hash function (an alphabetic one based on the file name), so the terminology still applies.

Comment: Eddie - this looks good but can you add a link or reference for this?